# Compute heliocentric ecliptic coordinates from Kepler's laws

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, orbital-elements

I'm writing a program to compute the heliocentric ecliptic position of planets and asteroids.  I want to output rectangular coordinates oriented [according to the ecliptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic_coordinate_system#/media/File:Heliocentric_rectangular_ecliptic.png): positive X in the direction of vernal equinox, positive Z toward the north ecliptic pole.

**My solution roughly matches other publicly available Kepler simulations (just eyeballing), but I think it is slightly off.  What is wrong and how do I verify it?**

Here is my process for calculating position at a given JD:

1. Pull in orbital elements from [JPL SSD website](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?planet_pos).  Specifically, the EM-Barycenter elements from [this table](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/txt/p_elem_t1.txt).
2. Compute period.  For example, in the case of Earth:

```
METERS_IN_AU = 149597870700
SECONDS_IN_DAY = 86400

GM_SUN = 1.3271244004193938E+20              // m^3/s^2
SEMIMAJOR_AXIS = 1.0000026 * METERS_IN_AU    // meters

period = 2 * PI * sqrt(SEMIMAJOR_AXIS^3 / GM_SUN)
periodInDays = period / SECONDS_IN_DAY
```

GM is from [NASA NAIF](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/pck/gm_de431.tpc). The above formula returns `periodInDays=365.2583228291575`, as opposed to the commonly cited 365.2422 days in a year.

3. Compute `meanMotion = 2 * PI / periodInDays` (radians per day)
4. Compute  mean anomaly at JD=2458563.415278 (spring equinox):

```
epoch = time of orbital elements (jd)
meanLon = mean longitude (radians)
lonPeri = longitude of perihelion (radians)

meanAnomalyAtEpoch = meanLon - lonPeri;
M = meanAnomalyAtEpoch + meanMotion * (2458563.415278 - epoch);
```

This can produce an unusually large angle. In this case, M=120.6878 radians!

5. Estimate eccentric anomaly `E` using iterative approximation:

```
    let E = M;
    let lastdiff;
    do {
      const E1 = M + e * sin(E);
      lastdiff = abs(E1 - E);
      E = E1;
    } while (lastdiff > 1e-6);
```

6. Compute true anomaly from eccentric anomaly E and eccentricity e:

```
v = 2 * atan(sqrt((1 + e) / (1 - e)) * tan(E / 2))
```

7. Compute radius in AU:

```
r = a * (1 - e * e) / (1 + e * cos(v));
```

8. Compute heliocentric coordinates:

```
o = longitude of ascending node (radians)
p = longitude of perihelion (radians)
i = inclination (radians)

X = r * (cos(o) * cos(v + p - o) - sin(o) * sin(v + p - o) * cos(i))
Y = r * (sin(o) * cos(v + p - o) + cos(o) * sin(v + p - o) * cos(i))
Z = r * (sin(v + p - o) * sin(i))
```

In the case of Earth with [these elements](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/txt/p_elem_t1.txt), I get the following outputs for JD=2443568.0 ([code here](https://jsfiddle.net/typpo/kp3n7u2o/15/)):

```
Period (days): 365.25832830801806 
Mean motion (rad/day): 0.01720203160400233 
Mean anomaly at epoch (rad): -0.043163916976385774 
Mean anomaly at JD 2458563.415278 (rad): 120.68783750518942 
Eccentric anomaly (rad): 120.70404042143021 
True anomaly (rad): 1.3397564871245002 
Radius (AU): 0.9959122843645666 
X coord (AU): -0.9958986393991808 
Y coord (AU): 0.005213270672998027 
Z coord (AU): -1.3930375794150342e-9
```

Given that JD=2458563.415278 is the vernal equinox, I would perhaps expect Y be closer to zero.